# Load content in Bootstrap tab after clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load content in tab after tab clicked. My code is this in twiter bootstrap:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active in" id="home">
        <!-- content 1-->
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="alumnos">
        <!-- content 2-->
    </div>
</div> <!-- <div id="myTabContent"> -->
```

Now I am loading all tabs contents on load page but When I clicked in tab I don't know how to include the external content. 
Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://blog.chewxy.com/2011/10/30/dynamically-loading-content-in-twitter-bootstrap-tabs/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to using ajax loading with bootstrap-tabs.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456974/how-to-using-ajax-loading-with-bootstrap-tabs-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can put buttons at the regions you want so to load when you click on them.