# Load html file in another html file for dynamic tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to implement dynamic tabs by following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h) link. It is straightforward to use. But to use this, all the HTML data should be on the same HTML file. How can I keep my HTML data in another file and use it when the respective tab is clicked?

**Edit:** I don't want the URL to change depending on the tab.

Comment: Load the tab content through AJAX. There are lots of tutorials on that if you Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap load tab from external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333113/bootstrap-load-tab-from-external-url)

Comment: @SunilKumar Not same, I didn't want the url to change depending on the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use load external file data on `shown.bs.tab` function using jQuery `.load()`. for updated reference you can go http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  // call jquery load() here
})
```