# Click action Jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
       <li class="dropdown">
                         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li id="mymenu">
                                <a href="#">Alert</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
        </li>
```

Jquery code is like below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mymenu").click(function(){
      alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
   });
  </script
```

I am using twitter bootstrap trying to display alert on click on dropdown
I am not able to perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a working example http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/8xfqcfuz/. You have to wrap your code like this and you have to have jquery loaded.

**HTML**

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="mymenu">
            <a href="#">Alert</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#mymenu").click(function(){
     alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
   });
});
```

Comment: Can we use load similar way load function
'code'
                 $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $("#tab2").click(function(){
                       $('#mydiv').load('l.html');
                    });
        });

Comment: Is not clear what is your question. You want to load your tabs dynamically?

Comment: Yes I want to load dynamically onclick

Comment: take a look around there are plenty of tutorials out of there but might this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456974/how-to-use-ajax-loading-with-bootstrap-tabs