# How to update content in Bootstrap tabpanel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

this is my first question in this site and I need some help.

I am creating a socialnetwork , facebook like style and I have a tabpanel with 2 tabs in bootstrap, the fist tab is "Friends", where the content of friends will be shown, and the second tab not so important as the fist one is called "Home" where all posts from the user will be placed.

In the first tab , I need to reload the content dinamically, by clicking this tab all new posts from friends must appear. (I have already done this).
It works now by refreshing all page, or F5. But I dont know how to do all this.

if code help, I paste here the html code:

```
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                  <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="friends" href="#friends">
                    <i class="fa fa-user">
                      Friends
                    </i>

                  </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation">
                  <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" href="#home">
                    <i class="fa fa-home">
                      Home
                    </i>

                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="friends" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
                  <p>
                    Friends
                  </p>

                  <p>
                    <?php ListFPosts($id_user);?>
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div id="home" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
                  <p>
                    Home
                  </p>

                  <p>
                    <?php ListMyPosts($id_user);?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I've read a lot of, and I think I need Ajax and I dont know this language yet, someone could help me?.

Some help please?

Thx in advance.

Comment: you need to do this with ajax.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service**

Comment: Yeah, but 'How' is the question. I have no idea of this language , and as I read , tell me if i'm wrong , with Ajax cannot call a php function....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456974/how-to-use-ajax-loading-with-bootstrap-tabs  this may help you more

Comment: @CarlosGarcía-BlancoSardinero does this help you?

Comment: Really dont know, i'm reading it all , but i'm really lost...

Comment: I've tryed that , but it doesnt work.

Comment: As I understand, On tab click, I must reload all the content of each tab-pane , this way , I will get all the updates.