# Putting Two Actions on one link using the Zend Framework

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, web-applications, zend-framework2

I'm new to the Zend framework and am trying to prevent my application from loading all of the necessary data at once and to wait until a button press.  However, I want to be able to toggle between the pages instead of loading a new page.  For instance, right now I have

```
<li><a href="#families" data-toggle="tab">Families</a></li
```

This will toggle to the proper page and show the heading that I want it to.  However, it will not get the data.   I added a second button

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->basePath();?>/project/advancedFamily">Families</a></li>
```

This button gets the data, but it redirects to the index tab, not to the #families tab. So I get the proper behavior if I click the second button (which get's the data), then the first button (which moves to the proper tab).  How can I combine these into one?

Comment: Perhaps try <?php echo $this->basePath();?>/project/advancedFamily#families

Comment: @paul It looks like it's still redirecting the index part of the page. However, it does change the url.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem correctly but this can be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456974/how-to-use-ajax-loading-with-bootstrap-tabs

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to doing something like this ?
https://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/2eTSL/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
      <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
      <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
      <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">

      </div>
    </div>
```

With Javascript :

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```