# How can I dynamically fetch data in Tabs and Pills using their IDs? Using PHP & Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am creating a module for Question and Answers and I need to fetch the data separatedly each.

I created a Tab where I'll click the Question I want to answers, and its children or the answer should match.

For visual reference, here is my problem

> I have this data that are all fetched, which should not be. That is why I created Tabs and Pills so I can separate questions and answers

**12** and **13** are the id number of each data

[image]

So in Tabs and Pills, I got this

> The problem of this, is that I cannot fetch the data dynamically, it just shows ID **13** data for question and answer. How can I change this dynamically so I can click back and forth the tabs and show the right data by its id?
>
> I need to fetch the ID **12** of the 1st Tab

[image]

So here is my view

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <?php foreach($questions as $question){ ?>
            <?php echo $question->id; ?>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $question->id ?>" role="tab"><h4><?php echo $question->question ?></h4></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="13" role="tabpanel">

        <div class="card" style="border:2px solid black;">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <?php foreach($this->question_model->findAnswersByQuestion($question->id) as $answer){ ?>
                        <?php if($answer->type_id==0): ?>

                                <input type="radio" name="question_<?php echo $question->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $answer->answer ?>" required/>
                                <?php echo $answer->answer; ?><hr>


                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($answer->type_id==1): ?>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter Answer" name="question_<?php echo $question->id; ?>" required/>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div><br>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to fetch? the title don't match code, you have the data your just not using bootstrap tabs correctly

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I need to fetch data ID **12** and **13** correctly and dynamically when I click on tabs. Is there a way to do it? thank you!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because right now, I can only fetch ID **13** on one tab. I cannot click the other tab though.

Comment: yeah with an ajax call

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you help with it please sir? I just need to bear with this problem for a time now

Comment: [How to use AJAX loading with Bootstrap tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456974/how-to-use-ajax-loading-with-bootstrap-tabs), but like I said you have the data with `findAnswersByQuestion`, you could place that in js an simply switch out some dom, no need to fetch it again.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - but the thing is this `<div class="tab-pane" id="13" role="tabpanel">` how can I make this to dynamic?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I still got `13` as my hard-coded value

Comment: Recheck the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior you have a `tab-pane` per tab, so foreach should be wrapping it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so should I just make a static value?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how about the `<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $question->id ?>" role="tab"><h4><?php echo $question->question ?></h4></a>` ? I need to fetched it by id?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry but the links you gave to me does not help my problem, it isnt related at all. but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the tabs structure, your looping over questions for `nav-item`, but not looping over for `tab-pane` which is why clicking the tab link does nothing.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach($questions as $question){ ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-<?php echo $question->id ?>" role="tab"><h4><?php echo $question->question ?></h4></a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <?php foreach($questions as $question){ ?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-<?= $question->id ?>" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="card" style="border:2px solid black;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <?php foreach($this->question_model->findAnswersByQuestion($question->id) as $answer){ ?>

                    <!-- form input $answer / item -->

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! I got the point.. Im going to let you know if Ill get it correctly. I really appreciate your help

Comment: np, if it is indeed ajax you need ill delEat my words.

Comment: Thanks :) just needed time to understand it all for beginner like me. still got the correct logic